# What are the steps to integrate JSTS library in OpenLayers

Tags: openlayers, jsts

I want to buffer a geometry. I checked the official doc of OpenLayers, but there there is no description how the JSTS is integrated.

How can I integrate JSTS in OpenLayers?

Comment: See the example https://openlayers.org/en/latest/examples/jsts.html